# Latexmk execute script to build dependencies

Tags: latexmk, scripts

for my thesis i need the results of some external scripts to be integrated in my document.

It should look like this:

- latexmk -pdf
- => external script starts
- wait until script is finished
- do the normal latexmk stuff

I hope someone can help me
Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What is the question? Where is the problem? Just put those commands into a shell script.